# Using mod_rewrite to redirect subdirectory to webroot with CakePHP app

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cakephp

Hey all, I have the following setup in my webroot:

```
/issues
    (Trac install)
/myapp
    (Cake install)
```

What I want to happen is that when I go to http://example.com/, it will pull up the cake app - basically, redirecting `^(.*)` to `myapp/$1` (but invisibly - the URL for users/login is http://example.com/users/login).  I have an exception for `/issues/`, which works fine - when I go to /issues/, it pulls up Trac.  But my Cake app keeps redirecting things to http://example.com/myapp/users/login, which I think is breaking my sessions, and in any case is not desirable.  I've tried to force such URLs back to the root using something like

```
RewriteRule ^myapp/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond  $1  !^(myapp|issues)/.*$
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ myapp/$1
```

...but to no avail.  I also have `RewriteBase /` in all of my CakePHP .htaccess files.

Any ideas as to how I can actually get this to do what I want it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks that this [link](http://www.ad7six.com/read/57-Production-style-on-a-shared-host) could help you. After that you should have a cleaner separation, in my opinion.

Comment: I don't remember what I ended up doing here, but I'll mark this as accepted, since it's the only answer.